# referencing objects in JSON

Tags: html, json, reference

I have a code as a shown below in which I am not sure how to do referencing.

```
<p id="demo" ></p>
    <p id="options"></p>
    <script>
        var myObj, myJSON, text, obj;
        myObj = {
            "quiz": {
                        "sport": {
                            "q1": {
                                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                                "options": [
                                    "New York Bulls",
                                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                                    "Golden State Warriros",
                                    "Huston Rocket"
                                ],
                                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
                            }
                        },
                        "maths": {
                            "q1": {
                                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                                "options": [
                                    "10",
                                    "11",
                                    "12",
                                    "13"
                                ],
                                "answer": "12"
                            }

                        }
                   }
        }
    //Storing data:
    // converting JS object into String
        myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
        localStorage.setItem("testJSON", myJSON);

    //Retrieving data:
        text = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");

    //converting String into JS object
        obj = JSON.parse(text);

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML    = // code
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes should I make in the below line(**which is the last line in the above code**) so that the output should be **Huston Rocket**.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML    = // code
```

I tried in the following way but somehow I am not able to reach **Huston Rocket**

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML    = myObj.quiz.sport.q1.answer;
```

Comment: What output are you getting? I'm getting "Huston Rocket" (with your code and `myobj`) as you said you wanted. Even your own fiddle outputs the same. So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: There is an extra line at the bottom which was causing an issue. Now its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect name, after Json parsing, your Json object is 'obj'
So use it as

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.quiz.sport.q1.answer;
```

Comment: No change. Are you sure `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.quiz.sport.q1.answer;` is right ?

Comment: I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wt95u71j/1/) for the above code. I just want to retrieve data similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lwaejsk/)

Comment: This answer is correct. In that fiddle, you need to comment out line 53 or set it to some value. It's currently set to a comment which is breaking the entire fiddle (opening up the dev console reveals this).

Comment: Oh yes, I removed that line and now its working properly.